# postgreSql Index not used after using custom function

Tags: postgresql

I defined a custom function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."div_zeroTest"("a" numeric, "b" numeric)
  RETURNS "pg_catalog"."numeric" AS $BODY$
    SELECT CASE b
    WHEN 0 THEN
        0
    ELSE
        a/b
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100
```

But when I used him, I found that using this function would invalidate the index
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4UOy.png)

If I use casewhen directly, it will still take effect
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43oDY.png)

why is it causing this

Comment: please don't use images for your query plans, prefer to copy-paste them as code blocks

Comment: concerning the question itself, it would be great if you pasted the index definition and the query

Answer (score 0):

Not enough details to be sure, but as a general rule, in order for a query that uses a function to use an index, you need to create an [expression index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html)
and use the same expression in your `where` clause as in your index definition.

Also the function must be marked `immutable` and not `volatile`, since your function is clearly pure (same input will always yield same output).